# Thread.Sleep() in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to make an image viewer in C# [Visual Studio 2010](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Visual_Studio_2010) which displays images one by one after seconds:

```
i = 0;

if (image1.Length > 0) //image1 is an array string containing the images directory
{
    while (i < image1.Length)
    {
        pictureBox1.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(image1[i]);
        i++;
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
    }
```

When the program starts, it stops and just shows me the first and last image.

Comment: You are blocking the UI thread..

Comment: You always override pictureBox1.Image

Comment: i guess it's sleeping inbetween ;) - Thread.Sleep(123) stops the whole thread which in this case includes the image display i guess without knowing your surrounding code - however, using a Timer might bring you more luck

Comment: Not sure why you were downvoted?  Seemed like a good question to me.

Comment: Same feeling as @Chad, +1 to OP.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Thread.Sleep blocks your UI thread use [System.Windows.Forms.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx) instead.

Comment: any special reason to use System.Windows.Forms.Timer?

Comment: @ChriPf because the Windows Forms timer tick events automatically runs on the UI thread.  No need to Invoke.

Comment: TO explain: The windows shows the picture when it redraws. THe redraw is a UI thread event. You block the thread, no UI updates - and no other UI interaction either, so no button clicks etc.

Answer (score 14):

Use a Timer.

First declare your Timer and set it to tick every second, calling `TimerEventProcessor` when it ticks.

```
static System.Windows.Forms.Timer myTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
myTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(TimerEventProcessor);
myTimer.Interval = 1000;
myTimer.Start();
```

Your class will need the image1 array and an int variable `imageCounter` to keep track of the current image accessible to the TimerEventProcessor function.

```
var image1[] = ...;
var imageCounter = 0;
```

Then write what you want to happen on each tick

```
private static void TimerEventProcessor(Object myObject, EventArgs myEventArgs) {
    if (image1 == null || imageCounter >= image1.Length)
        return;

    pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(image1[imageCounter++]);
}
```

Something like this should work.

Comment: I do not see System.Windows.Form.Timer on Visual Studio Mac classes. There is System.Threading.Timer but the syntax is different.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, because `Thread.Sleep` blocks the UI thread during the 2s.

Use a timer instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid using `Timer` and defining an event handler you can do this:

```
DateTime t = DateTime.Now;
while (i < image1.Length) {
    DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
    if ((now - t).TotalSeconds >= 2) {
        pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(image1[i]);
        i++;
        t = now;
    }
    Application.DoEvents();
}
```